# On solution of linear first order pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Please help me in this problem.
Show that the solution of the following problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $U$ identically zero.

$aU_x+ bU_y = -U$ where $U$ tends to zero as $x^2 + y^2$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Hint: what happens at local maximum or minimum points of $U$?

Comment: U is zero at local maximum/ minimum points but how can we conclude usin this and the given condition that U is entirely zero?

Comment: If $U$ were defined on a compact domain, and $U= 0$ on the boundary, we could say $U\equiv 0$ because if it weren't, it would have a nonzero interior max or min point, leading to a contradiction. For the given problem, you can take a large ball outside which $|U|\leq \epsilon$, argue similarly to show $|U|\leq\epsilon$ inside the ball, and send $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you.